# Netty4: Sending multiple request to different servers

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have one client which is sending multiple requests. Each request is going to different server. So, 200 requests going to 200 different servers.
I have created one even loop group with different bootstrap for different connection.
Should i use 200 channels for 200 requests or a single channel. Below is my code, right now i am using single channel:

```
public HttpClientDemo(int serverPort)
    {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.pipelineFactory = new HTTPClientInitializer();
        this.workerGroup =  new NioEventLoopGroup();
    }

    public void connect(String address, int timeout) {

            connectAsync(address).syncUninterruptibly();
    }   

    private ChannelFuture connectAsync(final String address)
    {
        return new Bootstrap()
                .group(workerGroup)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(pipelineFactory).connect(address,serverPort).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                        if(future.isSuccess())
                        {
                            log.info("Client is able to connect to: " + address);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            log.error("Client not able to connect to: " + address + " " +  future.cause());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Channel is connected to a different endpoint and so different server, this means you will need different Channels.